# How to specify srcset in a JSON object for fancybox 3?

Tags: fancybox-3

For fancybox 3, I can manually create a group of objects with a pattern

```
{
    src  : '' // Source of the content
    type : '' // Content type: image|inline|ajax|iframe|html (optional)
    opts : {} // Object containing item options (optional)
}
```

How can I specify srcset in this case for display different images based on viewport width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `image.srcset` option to set srcset attribute, example:

```
$.fancybox.open({
    src : 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=medium_1200%C3%97800&w=1200&h=720',
    type: 'image',
    image : {
      srcset : 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=large_1600%C3%97800&w=1600&h=960 1600w, https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=medium_1200%C3%97800&w=1200&h=720 1200w, https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=small_640%C3%97427&w=640&h=384 640w'
    }
  });
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aRWpQp?editors=1010

Note: there is an inconsistency across browsers about how this should work, for example, try that demo using Chrome and Firefox, and try resizing window. Firefox works as you might expect but Chrome probably not. Therefore it is planned for v4 to implement responsiveness a bit differently.

Comment: It seems to break if I use opts to specify caption or thumb: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPoYVb?editors=1010

Comment: Ten try setting options like this - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OBgVzb?editors=1010 or https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aRwOEX?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

So far, I've found a temporary solution. In JSON I added srcset:

```
var gallery = {
  "src" : "https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x300",
  "srcset" : "https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x300, https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600 2x"
}
```

Then used afterLoad:

```
$.fancybox.open(gallery, {
    afterLoad: function (instance, slide) {
        if (slide.srcset)
            slide.$slide.find(".fancybox-image").attr("srcset", slide.srcset);
        }
    });
```

Everything seems to be working correctly.

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oaWBMe?editors=1010

If I am wrong, please correct.